# Backend edit customer: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, customer, backend

Getting this error when trying to configure a customer, after clicking OK it does load. But what causes this? Thanks for who can help me!

[image: Error]

Comment: Are you sure that your admin theme template files haven't been modified? Did you try to turn off customer-related extensions and check if the error persists?

Answer (score 3):

The cause of this problem is the value of `is_required` in `postcode` field in `eav_attribute` is 0. You have 2 options to solve it:

1. Set this back to 1.
2. Update the file in `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\directory\js\optional_zip_countries.phtml` with the code from github here https://gist.github.com/alihalabyah/fba4660d0d3f4c3c85a3

I think this is a bug of Magento.

Comment: Setting is_required =1 in table eav_attribute resolved this issue for me. Will this cause a conflict for addresses in other countries?